# Use 'as Movie[]' instead of '<Movie[]>' @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions

Tags: typescript

I have a Vuex store:

```
type Movie = {
  title: string;
  id: number;
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searchList: <Movie[]>[],
  },
```

When I compile my code I get an error:

> Use 'as Movie[]' instead of '<Movie[]>'  @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions

It's not clear to me what the correct syntax should be.

I've tried:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searchList as Movie[]
  },
```

But this returns:

> No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'searchList'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.

Comment: declare the property like this  searchList: Movie[] = [],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is asking for is that you use the `as` [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to specify the type of `[]`.
One reason to use `as` is that `as` works in TSX files (thus the "consistent" in the name of the rule).

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searchList: [] as Movie[],
  },
```

If you are not using TSX and prefer the angle-bracket syntax, you can consider updating your linter rules.